# .droppable doens't give visual feedback on second drop

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-droppable

I've got multiple drag and drops (jquery-ui). In separated div's. When I drag the draggable and drop it outside the droppable and then drag it again and drop it on the droppable it doesn't give feedback ( like text or alert) only if you drop it in one go. It does keep snapping to the drop area.

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#eeneen.drag" ).draggable({ snap: ".drop1", snapMode: "inner"});
    $( ".drop1" ).droppable({
        accept: "#eeneen.drag",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
            .addClass("goed")
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Correct" );
                    alert ("correct");

        }
    });
});
```

this is repeated for every drag and drop. For some reason it would only give the visual feedback of the last function that's why I made multiple drop classes.

edit:
without the .addClass and .find still same problem.

any ideas?

Final edit. everything Works.

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#eendrie.drag" ).draggable({ snap: ".drop3", snapMode: "inner"});
    $( ".drop3" ).droppable({
        accept: "#eendrie.drag",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )

                .find( "p" )
                   $("#goed").toggle().hide(2000); 

        }
    });
});
```

So it has an extra div that shows and hides after a succesfull drop.

Also I defined the height and width of the .drag.ui-draggable. I guess that did it.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and mark is as answer for others who come across this :)